# Sequelize returning `null` object for hasOne association's linked model after bulk inserting pre-existed data

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

I have a pre-existing data in the form of JSON files which I am trying to insert into Sequelize SQLite table. I have 2 tables: `Master_Vessel` and `Requests`. There is a `Request.hasOne(Vessel)` association, meaning that every `request` has a `vessel` associated with it.

The key connecting both the models is `vessel.Vessel_Name`, which is a string. The data has been generated from a system which validates the keys so it is consistent (every `request.Vessel_Name` exists in `vessel.Vessel_Name`, `vessel.Vessel_Name` is unique).

I want to load this data into Sequelize managed table. I am creating the models as follows:

```
var Request = sequelize.define('request', {
     // other fields
     Vessel_Name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
     }
}, {
    tableName: 'Request'
});

var Vessel = sequelize.define('vessel', {
     // other fields
     Vessel_Name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true
     }
}, {
    tableName: 'Master_Vessel'
});
```

And, the association is as follows:

```
Request.hasOne(Vessel, {foreignKey: 'Vessel_Name', allowNull: true});
```

Now, I am loading the data in following steps:

1. Create and bulk load the `Vessel` model
2. Create the `Request` model, the association and bulk load the `Request` model

Everything runs fine without any issues. However when I try to query using the association as follows:

```
Request.findOne()
.then(request => {
    console.log(request.get())
    request.getVessel()
    .then(vessel => console.log(vessel))
});
```

`request` instance contains the `Vessel_Name` foreign key, however the `vessel` instance is `null`.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this is happenning because I got the Sequelize 'vocabulary' mixed up, `Request.hasOne(Vessel)` does NOT mean `Request` will have one `Vessel_Name` that will point to a `Vessel`. It is to be read R->L for correct meaning, not L->R.

The solution to the problem was changing the association from `hasOne` to `belongsTo` as follows: `Request.belongsTo(Vessel)`, so now the FK will be created on `Request`.

Quite a confusing choice of association names and semantics!